# webpack dev server serves javascript with the text/html mime type

Tags: javascript, service-worker, webpack-dev-server, create-react-app

I'm trying to add a custom service worker to a React app started with the CRA (Create React App) bootstrapping tool. I've added my custom service-worker Javascript to the build output folder and it is being served by webpack. However, I cannot register it because the webpack dev server is somehow serving the file with the mime type of "text/html". I've ejected my CRA scripts and added custom express configuration to the WebpackDevserver.config.js to mark all files that end with '.js' as text/javascript. I've done this with a before and after hook as follows:

```
before(app) {
  app.use(function jsContentTypeMiddleware(req, res, next) {
      if (req.url.endsWith('.js')) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
      }
      next();
    });
  // This lets us open files from the runtime error overlay.
  app.use(errorOverlayMiddleware());
  // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
  // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
  // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
  // it used the same host and port.
  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
  app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware());
},
after(app) {
  app.use(function jsContentTypeMiddleware(req, res, next) {
      if (req.url.endsWith('.js')) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
      }
      next();
    });
}
```

For some reason the mime type is still being received on the browser as "text/html" even after I confirm in a server debug session that the header is properly being set in the before hook. I was initially just using a before hook but then I added the after hook when I saw the content type was still being received in the browser with the "text/html" mime type. I get no breakpoint hits in the after hook so I cannot confirm that it is wired up or firing.

Is there a better way to do this? I really don't want to eject my CRA app. I've seen this as a common thread while Googling for advice. Apparently there is a project which can work around the pain of adding a custom service worker without ejecting but I haven't tried it. Looking through the source, I can't see how it would even work since it doesn't appear to adjust any webpack dev server configs. Please advise.

Comment: I had that once too - the error message was deceiving, though. The real cause was that the file wasn't being generated and that created a `404`.

Comment: In this case, I've confirmed via both client side and server side debugging that the file is being served. It's just being served with the wrong mime-type and I can't figure out where it's being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my problem was as locating my service worker file in the public directory, rather than the build output folder. (I was getting my wires crossed because I use the build folder to deploy the app on my TV set as well.) In actuality, webpack was never finding my custom service worker js file and instead serving up the default html index page. Locating the file in the appropriate place is all I needed to do and I didn't need to eject at all.